# Test key events on React.JS with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I've been trying to use key events with Enzyme test utility but I'm having no success. I've tried

```
combo.find(".searchInput").simulate("keydown", { keyCode: 40 });
```

and

```
combo.find(".searchInput").simulate("keydown", { target: { keyCode: 40 } });
```

but none seem to work. Does anyone knows the correct syntax to simulate key events with Enzyme?

Answer (score 3):

There are two potential issues.  The first is that you need to camelCase "keyDown" instead of "keydown".  The second is that you may need to pass in more data regarding the key code you're checking.

```
combo.find(".searchInput").simulate("keyDown", { target: {
  keyCode: 40,
  which: 40,
  key: "Down Arrow"  // not sure if this is right, you might need to debug to inspect the real value in console
} });
```

Comment: I've tried something like that, I've looked up the key names in this list  [link](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-key-codes) but that doesn't work either

Comment: In this expression target is not needed, like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47639464/3460363