# enzyme wrapper.find(..).simulate keypress doesnt trigger event listener

Tags: javascript, testing, event-listener, enzyme

I am trying to press **enter** on one of the input boxes. Doing it manually triggers the event listener, however, while trying with enzyme, the event listener is not triggered. What am I doing wrong here?

> Event Listener

```
this.input.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
            debugger;
            onEnter(event);
        });
```

> Enzyme

```
function setup(store, props) {
    return mount(<Provider store={store}>
            <component{...props}/>
        </Provider>
    );
}

beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = setup(store, {});
        searchBar = wrapper.find('searchBar');
        searchInput = searchBar.find("input");
    });

it("when enter is pressed, event should be triggered", ()=> {
            let wait = false;
            runs(()=> {
                searchInput.simulate('change', {target: {value: 'helloWorld'}});
                searchInput.simulate('keyPress', {which: 13});
                setTimeout(()=> {
                    wait = true;
                }, 1000);
            })

            waitsFor(()=> {
                return wait;
            }, "", 1500);
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this problem too. But now I`ve found a solution.
In addition to `{ which: 13 }` parameter, you need to specify at least `key` parameter, so your simulate expression will be like:

```
searchInput.simulate('keyPress', {
    key: 'Enter',
    keyCode: 13,
    which: 13,
});
```

Comment: I realised I was targeting the parent `<div />` of the component, but the `onKeyPress` was on the first direct child, so I needed to target that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Enzyme, built for React testing, likely doesn't know about your native JavaScript event listener. If you bind the event with JSX, Enzyme should be able to pick it up. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Change this:

```
this.input.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
    debugger;
    onEnter(event);
});
```

To this:

```
<searchBar>
    <input onKeypress={this.onEnter.bind(this)} aria-label="Search" />
</searchBar>
```